# Not getting milliseconds in MySQL when inserting from Sails

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I'm using `MySQL 5.7.13` with `sails 0.12.3` and `sails-mysql 0.12.2`. I want to insert a new record with a `timestamp` field which, in `beforeCreate` for that model, logs as value for the field the following:

> 2016-07-13T16:37:21.529Z

The definition of the field for the model is type `datetime`. It seems that the field is in correct format (ISO) but when I check the record directly from mysql command line I get always 000 in the milliseconds part, e.g.

> 2016-07-13T16:37:21.000

After checking and searching, I cannot find where the problem is. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like fractional seconds aren't supported by `sails-mysql`.

The code to create a `datetime` field ([here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/blob/95c07ef4904e0ae12b8dd2e8eeb704465b5b0b63/lib/sql.js#L470-L472)) doesn't declare fractional seconds (so MySQL [defaults to 0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)), and the code to convert `Date` instance to SQL ([here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/blob/95c07ef4904e0ae12b8dd2e8eeb704465b5b0b63/lib/sql.js#L495-L505)) only has 1-second resolution.

Someone [attempted to add fractional second support](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/pull/308) some time ago but that PR got closed and it doesn't look something similar was ever merged.

Comment: As @robertklep points out, there is no other way than modifying certain files in `sails-mysql` module. The ones to be modified are: `lib/sql.js` and `lib/utils.js`. There, `DATETIME` is replaced by `DATETIME(3)` and `toSqlDate()` function is as follows:

`date = date.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ('00' + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('00' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
    ('00' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
    ('00' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + '.' +
    ('00' + date.getMilliseconds()).slice(-2);
`